# checking for username in database exists or not

Tags: asp.net

I want that if a user enters a username and as soon as he clicks tab or goes to the next option, a validation should be displayed whether the username is available or does not exist in the database. I don't want to use the functionality of the button of check availablity.

Comment: So what's hard about it?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to do that.

Comment: use [leave-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) of the field you are using to obtain the username! Check the value in field against database?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, I think he has to use "onchange" event

Comment: @milanm: On change will not work! let say you have username `abc` on databse and you are trying to enter `abcde` what will happen here?

Comment: i am new to programming. Instead of Ajax could u pls tell me to use it through stored procedure?

Comment: What kind of moron goes: "hey, this sounds like the perfect problem to give the guy who knows next to nothing about programming?"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-check-username-availability.html this might help it uses ajax .

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple webservice that takes string as an argument and returns true/false as reply based on the availability of the username.

Now create a javascript function and call this webservice through the javascript function.

Call this javascript function on the "onchange" event of the input element(textbox) where user is entering the username.

Put a span element in-front of the textbox(input) and show relevant message based on the availability of the username.

That's it.

You can find the code on the following URL:
[validate username ajax and json and asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241275/validate-username-ajax-and-json-and-asp-net/5241466#5241466)

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st make textbox is autopostback =true

   1. 2nd go to events of the text box and go to textchanges event that will fire as soon as you make tab or textbox unfocused
   2. 3rd write the code that get the username from db and check exist or not from here
      protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      //get user name from db
      }